# i have vendor.js and main.js in angular app , i want to defer load those scripts

Tags: angular, deferred-loading

[my console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOPkF.png) in the following images i have vendor.js and main.js in angular app , i want to defer load those scripts but where to do it in my project
this is my component.ts

```
  getProductById(id: any): any {
    return this.products.find((product) => product._id === id);
  }
  increase(id: any): void {
    let product = this.getProductById(id);
    product.quantity = product.quantity + 1;
  }
  decrease(id: any): void {
    let product = this.getProductById(id);
    if (product.quantity > 0) product.quantity = product.quantity - 1;
  }
  addToCart(id: any): void {
    let product = this.getProductById(id);
    this.totalItem = this.totalItem + product.quantity;
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DeferLoding</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the index.html file, and remove the related script tags where these files are loading.

Comment: @VinaySomawat there are no script tags in index.html